# settings for a sync adapter / authenticator

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-syncadapter

I have problems with the settings for a sync adapter / authenticator. I can add CheckBoxPreferences, SwitchPreferences and PreferenceScreens but I don't know how to set up the settings for the accounts sync :-(
When I tap on the sync entry I see this screen on the right side. But I want a screen where I can switch the sync on and off... like the account setting from my Google account.

How to do that?

[image]

Comment: could you add some how to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I found it. I have to set the sync adapter visible:

```
android:userVisible="true"
```